# Arrow and tab navigation on Primefaces Tree Component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

To make our application WAI-ARIA conformant, i would like to enable the users to be able to navigate, expand, close nodes on a Primefaces tree compoponent using the arrows, tabs and enter keys. On the PF [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/events.xhtml), I see that the tree is navigable using these keys but when I implement my own, I cant. Could anybody enlighten me how I could achieve this.

Can someone also confirm to me that this feature is only available in the Elite version of Primefaces 5.1.X? If so does anyone know when it would be available on the community version?

I am using the PF 5.1 community version on tomcat 7 container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to find in the PF [issuelist](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7631) and [blog](http://blog.primefaces.org/?paged=2)

Answer: Yes, since 5.1.3, 
Answer 2: So it will be in a community version for 5.2

How to do this yourself? I'd try to download the tree.js source from PrimeFaces SVN from 5.1 and trunk, compare and try to patch the existing code