# Primefaces Tree Navigation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tree

As a follow-up to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302038/arrow-and-tab-navigation-on-primefaces-tree-component) I had asked before, now that primefaces 5.2 is available, I cannot seem to get the tree to be navigated using arrow keys. As I mentioned before, in the showcase, one can use the arrow-keys to navigate, expand or collapse nodes. Using exactly the same code locally does not however allow this arrow-keys navigation.

Is there a specific attribute i need to add to the tree element?

How does one enable arrow-keys navigation, expand and context?

here is the tree snippet:

```
                        <p:tree  value="#{treeEventsView.root}"   var="doc" selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeEventsView.selectedNode}" dynamic="true">
                        <p:ajax event="expand" update=":form:messages" listener="#{treeEventsView.onNodeExpand}"  />
                        <p:ajax event="collapse"  listener="#{treeEventsView.onNodeCollapse}" />
                        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeEventsView.onNodeSelect}" />
                        <p:ajax event="unselect"  listener="#{treeEventsView.onNodeUnselect}" />
                        <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed" ariaLabel="Folder" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}"/>
                        </p:treeNode>
                        <p:treeNode type="document" icon="ui-icon-document">
                            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                        <p:treeNode type="picture" icon="ui-icon-image">
                            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                        <p:treeNode type="mp3" icon="ui-icon-video">
                            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                    </p:tree>
```

Comment: There are **multiple** showcase examples, so which one. Some do not have keyboard navigation (the basic one) ? The differences I noticed between the 'basic' example and the events one are 'selection' and 'dynamic'. Did you **try** to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @kikeltje, as you can see, am basically using the exact code in the event- based example.

Comment: Then look for client-side javascript errors and check if you REALLY are using 5.2 (check for duplicate jars)